# Ajuda com Editor de Texto em C

Tags: c

Estou tendo alguns problemas em fazer um editor de texto ai vai alguns deles:

1 - Eu não sei como fazer para apagar uma linha;

2 - Eu não consigo movimentar com as setas do mouse para cima e editar uma linha do texto e salvar em sequencia;

3 - Colocar opções como `ctrl+s` pra salvar `ctrl+f` pra procurar;

Este é meu código, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria, sou iniciante em C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

#define praCima 72
#define praCima 72
#define praBaixo 80
#define enter 13
#define esc 27

typedef struct reg no;

struct reg{
    char infoLinha[100];
    no *prox, *ant;
};

void cria_lista (no *lista)
{
     lista = NULL;
} 

void exibeTexto(no *lista, int sel) {
    no *atual;
    atual = lista;
    int cont = 0;
    while(atual != NULL) {
        if (sel >= 0)
            printf("%c %s\n", ((sel == cont) ? '>' : ' '), atual->infoLinha);
        else
            printf("%s%s", ((cont == 0) ? " " : "\n "), atual->infoLinha);
        cont++;
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}

no* Nelemento(no *lista, int n, int tam) {
    int cont = 0;
    no *elemento;
    elemento = lista;
    if (n > tam-1)
        return NULL;
    while (cont < n) {
        elemento = elemento->prox;
        cont++;
    }       
    return elemento;
}

void escreve() {
    no *lista;
    int sel = 0;
    int tam = 0;
    cria_lista(lista);
    lista = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
    lista->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
    tam++;
    strcpy(lista->infoLinha, "");
    no* atual;
    atual = lista;
    int sai = 0;

    char op = 0;
    do {
        system("cls");
        exibeTexto(lista, sel);
        printf("\n\n\t <ENTER> SELECIONAR | <ESC> SAIR");
        op = getch();
        switch(op) {
            case enter:     
                system("cls");
                fflush(stdin);
                atual = Nelemento(lista, sel, tam);
                no *p;
                p = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
                p->prox = atual;
                p->ant = atual->ant;                
                gets(p->infoLinha);

                atual->ant = p;
                if (p->ant != NULL)
                    p->ant->prox = p;
                if(p->prox == lista)
                    lista = p;
                tam++;
                sel = tam-1;

                break;
            case esc:
                sai = 1;
                break;
            case praCima:
                if (sel > 0)
                    sel--;
                break;
            case praBaixo:
                if (sel < tam-1)
                    sel++;
                break;
        }
        if (sai)
            break;
    } while(op != '2');
}

void escreveSalva() {
    no *lista;
    FILE *arquivo;
     if ((arquivo = fopen("linhas.txt", "r+b")) == NULL) {
        if ((arquivo = fopen("linhas.txt", "wb")) == NULL) {
         printf ("\nErro da abertura do arquivo.\n\n");
         getch();
         return;
        }    
     }
    int sel = 0;
    int tam = 0;
    cria_lista(lista);
    lista = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
    lista->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
    tam++;
    strcpy(lista->infoLinha, "");
    no* atual;
    atual = lista;
    int sai = 0;

    char op = 0;
    do {
        system("cls");
        exibeTexto(lista, sel);
        printf("\n\n\t <ENTER> SELECIONAR | <ESC> SAIR");
        op = getch();
        switch(op) {
            case enter:     
                system("cls");
                fflush(stdin);
                atual = Nelemento(lista, sel, tam);
                no *p;
                p = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
                p->prox = atual;
                p->ant = atual->ant;                
                gets(p->infoLinha);

                atual->ant = p;
                if (p->ant != NULL)
                    p->ant->prox = p;
                if(p->prox == lista)
                    lista = p;
                tam++;
                sel = tam-1;
                if(p->infoLinha != NULL)
                {                   
                   fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", p->infoLinha);
                }
                break;
            case esc:
                sai = 1;
                break;
            case praCima:
                if (sel > 0)
                    sel--;
                break;
            case praBaixo:
                if (sel < tam-1)
                    sel++;
                break;
        }       
        if (sai)                
           break;       
    } while(op != '2');
}

void menu()
{
    char tc;
    int i,sai=0,sel=0;
    int tamMenu=2;
    while (!sai)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Selecione uma das opcoes:\n\n\n");
        char menu[2][50]={"Escrever informacoes e salvar em arquivo","Apenas escrever informacoes sem salvar"};
        for (i=0;i<tamMenu;i++)
        {
            if (sel==i)
            {
                printf("\t      > ");
            }
            else printf("\t        ");
            printf("%s\n",menu[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n\t <ENTER> SELECIONAR | <ESC> SAIR");
        tc = getch();
        switch(tc)
        {
            case praCima: if (sel>0) { sel--; } else sel=tamMenu-1;
            break;
            case praBaixo: if (sel<tamMenu-1) { sel++; } else sel=0;
            break;
            case enter:
                switch(sel)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        escreveSalva();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        escreve();
                    }
                    break;                  
                }
            break;
            case esc: sai=1;
                break;
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá, Giovanni. Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sua pergunta, do jeito que está, está muito ampla. Tente quebrá-la em dúvidas mais específicas (e menores) e terá uma chance maior de encontrar ajuda.

Comment: É C ou C++? Nem sempre o que se faz em uma serve pra outra.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Mesmo que seja c++ parece que o Giovanni não está a utilizar nenhumas especifidades da linguagem.

Comment: Você sabe alguma coisa sobre estruturas de dados? Listas invertidas, B-tree, essas coisas?

Comment: @Intruso sim, sim revolvi o problema de apagar e movimentar a seta porem nao consigo editar aquela lista e somento apagar o ultimo elemento da lista, outra coisa que nao achei foi como ler ctrl+alguma tecla

Comment: @Giovanni Qual compilador e S.O. (nome e versão) você está usando para desenvolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está em considerar a representação visual do texto (arquivo) parte das funções de edição, tendo assim que manipular a tela durante ações que não são parte da necessidade de edição. (Ficou filosófico não foi?);

Percebi que sua estrutura de dados para o arquivo é baseada em uma lista encadeada para as linhas do documento, quando na verdade, você deveria consistir informação para uma forma mais granular (caracteres? palavras?). Isso porque você vai precisar guardar informação de formatação e posicionamento na mesma granularidade do posicionamento e ai a movimentação no texto seria apenas uma um ponteiro para a estrutura atual na lista duplamente encadeada.

Essa estrutura mais granular também facilita a edição, porque o loop principal é apenas um check do botão pressionado no teclado, e altera os ponteiros para próximo e anterior na posição atual da lista.

Algo do tipo:

```
struct reg{
    char letra;/*guarda o caractere, inclusve '\n' */
    int tamanho;
    int fontStyle; /*0 para normal, 1 para negrito, 2 para italico*/
    no *prox, *ant;
};
```

Quanto a tela, basta um clear e um **printAllNodes** para atualizar o lugar do ponteiro de edição a cada movimentação do mouse ou teclado. A posição do No atual na lista é a posição do cursor, bem fácil.

Atenção aqui, **não** use um Vetor para representar o seu texto. Apesar da estrutura de dados ser mais fácil de manter, percorrer e etc. Vetores tem seu espaço de alocação criado em tempo de compilação e ou aloca tudo ou nada. Além disso, o indice de manipulação do vetor está associado ao suporte a inteiros do seu compilador, logo, o indice maximo do vetor vai ser o inteiro maximo do sistema.

Agora vem a parte um pouco mais complicada, a estrutura de dados para pesquisa e localização. Bom, de cara, todos os algoritmos de pesquisa aplicados a listas pode ser usados facilmente aqui. Porque a sua estrutura interna do documento é basicamente um 'vetor' com mais informações sobre o ponteiro atual. ;)

Por uma questão de visualização, você precisa bloquear o texto enquanto esta procurando. Então, precisa de um modo de edição e um modo de procura no programa.

A diferença básica é o loop principal em cada modo, na edição você aceita os comandos necessários para edição (letras, delete, espaço, nova linha, etc e um comando Localizar).

Já no modo de localização, você só aceita 'sair' (volta ao modo edição), procurar (pesquisa uma palavra) e 'localizar proximo'.

Suponho que assim fique tudo mais fácil.